# How can i use factory function for different AngularJS controllers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a factory function that i want to use in three different controllers, I want to use if factory code block inside if condition of controller and else factory code block i want to use in else condition of controller. How to achieve this task using factory any help will be appreciated.

So far tried code below...

Factory.js

```
        angular.module("App").factory('geoTreeFactory', function() {
            return {
  getTreeCheck: function (geoLocation) {
      if (geoLocation.id === 5657){
        $.each(geoLocation.parent(),function(index,location) {
          if (location.id !== geoLocation.id) {
            $.each(location._childrenOptions.data.items,function(index,child){
              var disableChildId = 'disabled' + child.id;
              var model = $parse(disableChildId);
                model.assign($scope, true);
            })
            var disableItemId = 'disabled' + location.id;
            var model = $parse(disableItemId);
            model.assign($scope, true);
          }
        });
      }
      // If a child is checked Disable the parents
      try {
          var parent = geoLocation.parent().parent();
          var disableParentId = 'disabled' + parent.id;
          var parentModel = $parse(disableParentId);
          parentModel.assign($scope, true);
      } catch (err) {
     // Ignore since this happens when a node is selected which has no children 
        }
     //Expand and collapse tree on parent check so childrens can be disabled.
      $scope.riskInPrcsgeoLocationTree.expand($scope.riskInPrcsgeoLocationTree.findByText(geoLocation.text));
      $scope.riskInPrcsgeoLocationTree.collapse($scope.riskInPrcsgeoLocationTree.findByText(geoLocation.text));
      //If the parent item is checked, disable all the children
      if(geoLocation.items) {
          $.each(geoLocation.items,function(index,location) {
            var disableItemId = 'disabled' + location.id;
            var model = $parse(disableItemId);
            model.assign($scope, true);
          });
      } 
      },

      //Else block function if ocnditions are false
      getTreeUncheck: function(geoLocation) {
        if (geoLocation.id === 5657){
          var getParent = geoLocation.parent();
          $.each(geoLocation.parent(),function(index,location) {
            if (location.id !== geoLocation.id) {
              $.each(location._childrenOptions.data.items,function(index,child){
                var disableChildId = 'disabled' + child.id;
                var model = $parse(disableChildId);
                  model.assign($scope, false);
              })
              var disableItemId = 'disabled' + location.id;
              var model = $parse(disableItemId);
              model.assign($scope, false);
            }
          });
        }
        // If child is unchecked Enable the parent
        try {
          var parent = geoLocation.parent().parent();
          var checkedChildrens = [];
          for (var i=0; i<selectedRiskGeoLocations.length; i++){
            var checkNodes = selectedRiskGeoLocations[i];
            checkedChildrens.push(checkNodes);
          }
          if (checkedChildrens.length === 0){
            var disableParentId = 'disabled' + parent.id;
            var parentModel = $parse(disableParentId);
            parentModel.assign($scope, false);
          };
      }
        catch (err) {
          // Ignore since this happens when a node is selected which has no children 
        }
        //If the parent item is unchecked,  enable the childrens
        if(geoLocation.items){
            $.each(geoLocation.items,function(index,location){
              var disableItemId = 'disabled' + location.id;
              var model = $parse(disableItemId);
              model.assign($scope, false);
            });
        }
      }
};
```

Controller.js

```
var selectedCtlGeoLocations = [];
                    var selectedCtlGeoLocationIds = [];
                    $scope.populateControlInPrcsGeoLoction = function(geoLocation) {
                        var pos = $.inArray(geoLocation.text,selectedCtlGeoLocations);
                        if (pos < 0) {
                            selectedCtlGeoLocations.push(geoLocation.text);
                            selectedCtlGeoLocationIds.push(geoLocation.id);

                            // If the parent item is checked, disable all the
                            // children
                         geoTreeFactory.getTreeIfBlock();

                        } else {
                            selectedCtlGeoLocations.splice(pos, 1);
                            selectedCtlGeoLocationIds.splice($.inArray(
                                    geoLocation.id, selectedCtlGeoLocationIds),
                                    1);

                            // If the parent item is unchecked, enable the
                            // children
                            geoTreeFactory.getTreeElseBlock();
                        }

                    };
```

Comment: Can you post the least amount of code required to demonstrate the issue?  There's a lot of logic in there that is cluttering your question and I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: reduced amount of code...

Comment: So, in your controller, if you hit the `if` block, you want to hit the `if` statement in the service, and if you hit the `else` block in your controller, hit the `else` in your service?  No, there's no way to do that without satisfying the `else` condition.  But, if you know that that's the case, why not have two totally different functions, and call them straight from your controller.

Comment: why dont you pass an argument to the function? (maybe I didnt understand it very well)

Comment: @Tom i am confused so you are saying for if and esle i should have two different fucntions and call them from controller. How we will satisfy else condition in that case..

Comment: Well, your situation is not ideal and I still don't understand entirely what you're asking based on your code (you show no calls to `geoTreeFactory`)

Comment: Yes i did not make any call yet i am not sure how to implement factory in this situation..

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I could be way off here, but is this what you're trying to do?

```
app.factory('myservice', function(){
  return {
    ifBlock: function(){
      // code to run if condition is true
    },
    elseBlock: function(){
      // code to run if condition is false
    }
  }
});

app.controller('main', function(myservice){
  $scope.myevent = function(geoLocation){
    if(condition){
      myservice.ifBlock(geoLocation);
    } else {
      myservice.elseBlock(geoLocation);
    }
  }
});
```

You could also solve this problem like this (and if I understand your problem correctly, this is probably the preferred method):

```
app.service('myservice', function(){
  return {
    go: function(geoLocation){
      if(condition){
        // code to run if condition is true
      } else {
        // code to run if condition is false
      }
    }
  }
});

app.controller('main', function(myservice){
  $scope.myevent = function(geoLocation){
    myservice.go(goeLocation);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks i used your approach i was able to call factory conditions in controller but i am getting geoLocation is undefined. Do i need to pass that param in factory.

Comment: i added new code in question please take a look. i will appreciate your help.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like geoLocation is coming from your controller, so you'll need to pass that into the ifBlock and elseBlock functions. Also, you may want to pick more meaningful names for these functions.

Comment: I added scope in a factory but still getting this Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- geoTreeFactory

Comment: $scope is not available for factories. You could inject $rootScope, but I'm not sure what you would need a scope for?  What is it you are trying to accomplish with $scope?

Comment: hmm because my whole implementation of enable/disable checkboxes based on $scope.Tried $rootScope but still $scope' is undefined. Should i change factory to service ?

Comment: Usually it's a bad idea to update the $scope in a service or factory. Perhaps if I had a better, _high-level_ overview of what you're trying to accomplish, I could better answer your question.

Comment: I have treeview dropdown where i am disabling childrens if parent is selected and vice versa. so  $scope.populateControlInPrcsGeoLoction is one controller function that is on checkboxes  i want to call factory function to be executed that will do all enable/disable functionality for dropdowns...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75978/discussion-between-threed-and-aftab).

Comment: You'll want to investigate directives for this kind of functionality.